# Lightbox2 not preventing the browser from following link

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I'm trying to use [Lightbox2](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), and I've set up the `data-lightbox` attribute correctly (demonstrated by the mouseover case below). If I modify the Lightbox JS code to replace:

```js
$("body").on("click", ...)
```

to

```js
$("body").on("mouseover", ...)
```

the lightbox works just fine.

When the event is "click", however, the browser navs to the destination rather than simply displaying the referenced image in the lightbox. The full click listener callback is:

```js
      $('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
          self.start($(event.currentTarget));
          return false;
    });
```

... which should stop the browser from following the link (because of the `return false;`).

The JS console isn't displaying any errors, so I believe the `self.start(...)` aspect is working fine, and again, if I simply replace `click` with `mouseover` the lightbox works as expected.

Has anyone else experienced this (and know of a workaround and of what might be the problem)?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the click event, you can run `event.preventDefault()`. This will disable all actions the browser would normally do, such as following a link.

Here is the MDN documentation for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    self.start($(event.currentTarget));
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work. I think the fundamental problem is for some reason the 'click' event is simply not detected/handled ... i.e. I don't think the callback is being called at all. And yet, if I simply change the event to mouseover, the callback _is_ called, so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, I figured it out. I'm using a DataTables plugin that's stopping all anchor clicks (unless the meet a certain condition).

Nevermind!